# Yii2 Form AjaxValidation

Tags: php, yii2

I try to validate some field after client input but to server allays are sending values of ALL elements How to get post request only with one element not with all? Myform.php

```
$form=\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'validationUrl'=>\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['validate'])]);

echo $form->field($answers_list[202],"answer",['selectors' => ['input' => "#tanswers202-answer"]])
        ->textInput(['class'=>'form-control tmc','id'=>"tanswers202-answer",'name'=>"TAnswers[202][answer]"])->label(false);
echo $form->field($answers_list[203],"answer",['selectors' => ['input' => "#tanswers203-answer",'id'=>'203']])
    ->textInput(['class'=>'form-control tmc','id'=>"tanswers203-answer",'name'=>"TAnswers[203][answer]"])->label(false);


\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
```

The post request looks like this :

```
array (size=2)  'TAnswers' =>     array (size=1)      'answer' =>         array (size=20)          36 => string '123' (length=3)          37 => string '23' (length=2)          38 => string '3afasf' (length=6)          39 => string '4' (length=1)          40 => string '6' (length=1)          45 => string '' (length=0)          46 => string '' (length=0)          47 => string '' (length=0)          48 => string '' (length=0)          49 => string '' (length=0)          50 => string '' (length=0)          51 => string '' (length=0)          52 => string '' (length=0)          53 => string '' (length=0)          54 => string '123' (length=3)          55 => string '' (length=0)          56 => string '' (length=0)          57 => string '' (length=0)          58 => string '' (length=0)          59 => string '' (length=0)  'ajax' => string 'w0' (length=2)
```

But should be some like this :

```
array (size=2)  'TAnswers' =>     array (size=1)      'answer' =>         array (size=20)   'ajax' => string 'w0' (length=2)
```

MyController.php

```
 public function actionValidate()
    {
        $model = new TAnswers();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
```

}

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. 

Why do you need to do that? Why only validate 1 attribute? You always validate a model not 1 field. What if I have 1 field that depends on another one?

What is exactly the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: @MihaiP. 
 
1)Why do you need to do that?- I got a few same models with different values in my form 2)"Why only validate 1 attribute?" - to use different validation scenario depends on some id or another field 3)"What if I have 1 field that depends on another one?"- what do you mean? 4) There is a lot of questions ,for each question is answer model , depends on each question type should be different validation

Answer (score 0):

This is how yii active form works: On each ajax validation the entire form is sent. The entire form is validated however only the error for the current field (the one you just left) is show by default (you can show errors for other fields if you want it takes a little javascript to do).

What you are trying to do is to validate a model that is not the same model that is used to show the form. Basically it has nothing to do with the model in the active form.

You have 2 options (a good one and a bad one however you will choose the bad one and regret it afterwards):

1) create a proper model for the form and validate it. Harder to do but this is your actual proper answer. Take a look at the contact form model that comes with the yii installation. There is nothing stopping you from creating the rules and attributes arrays dynamically based on "stuff". On top of this it will make validating the entire form easy.
2) stop using enableAjaxValidation for your form and trigger the validation yourself on blur with just that field. This looks like the easy option but have fun with it.

PS: I have the exact same requirements for something. A form made up of questions, each question is it's own model saved in it's own row with EAV. Eventually you will get to a requirement that one question depends on an answer of another and then will immediately regret option 2.